# SQL - find max temp and its time

Tags: mysql, sql

I have got a table called raw_data with colums as shown in the picture. [image: table "raw_data"]

I would like to find max value of column "temp_out" between given times, get that max value and time when there was max value.

My code is:

```
SELECT time, temp_out AS temp_out_max
                FROM raw_data
                WHERE temp_out = (SELECT MAX(temp_out)
                      FROM raw_data
                      WHERE time BETWEEN '$time_yesterday' AND '$time_yesterday_2' 
                                 )
```

It finds max value between given times, however it doesnt return time which matches max value between given times.

Whats wrong? I tried everything... Thank you in advance for your reply.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the time constraint on the outer query, too:

```
SELECT time
    , temp_out AS temp_out_max
FROM raw_data
WHERE temp_out = (
    SELECT MAX(temp_out)
    FROM raw_data
    WHERE time BETWEEN '$time_yesterday' AND '$time_yesterday_2' 
    )
-- Add this line:    
AND time BETWEEN '$time_yesterday' AND '$time_yesterday_2';
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast reply @RussellFox ! It works pretty nice right now.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for one row, then you can do:

```
SELECT time, temp_out AS temp_out_max
FROM raw_data
WHERE time BETWEEN ? AND ?
ORDER BY temp_out DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;
```

The `?` are placeholders for parameters.  That is how you should be passing constant values into your queries.

`FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY` is standard SQL syntax.  Some databases use `SELECT TOP` or `LIMIT`.  MySQL uses `LIMIT`.

Comment: How could this attract a downvote, particularly an anonymous downvote?